# Jsp ActionErrors Struts

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-action

Good Afternoon in my timezone.

I am finalizing a Java Web project to a company, and i need to write errors detected in the actionForm validation method.
Inside the validate method i am adding errors that way (snippet of code):

```
ActionErrors ae = new ActionErrors();
ae.add("dummy",new ActionMessage("message"));
...java...code
 ae.add("dummy",new ActionMessage("message"));
```

In my jsp what i want to do is iterate over all the errors found it , and print them.
i do not want to put all the errors by the following way :

```
<html:errors property="prop1"/>
<html...code/>
<html:errors property="prop2"/>
```

What i want to do is something like this (psedo-code):

```
if(there is errors)
   for(erros.hasNext)
      <td>errors.next()</td>
```

I can use normal scriplets if i have to.
Can any body help me hear ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Just use `<html:errors/>`. See http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#errors for how the tag works:

> property  Name of the property for which error messages should be
>   displayed. **If not specified, all error messages (regardless of
>   property) are displayed**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: but how i control the display of the message ?
if just use <html:error/>, this would print a table , a list ?
I want to control that , and i want to some html id to each of the error messages

Comment: This is described in the documentation I linked to. You may have custom header and footer, and custom prefix and suffix. I don't really see how an ID could be useful. You may also loop over all the errors using the `<html:messages>` tag, described on the same page, if you need more flexibility.

Comment: @tt0686 Adding an ID to each error element seems a little pointless, if anything, use a class. Still not necessary, though, as you could embed them within another DOM container and use CSS to style its children.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to generate Javascript array of errors, your case should be very similar. Please note using html:messages instead of html:errors

```
<logic:messagesPresent>    
    ErrorMessages = new Array ();
     <html:messages id="message"> 
         ErrorMessages.push("<bean:write name='message' filter='false'/>");
    </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
<logic:messagesNotPresent>
//some logic here
</logic:messagesNotPresent>
```